# How do I use Open Solver in Excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a problem that has a lot of variables and the normal excel solver takes a lot of time to solve the problem. I am using the excel opensolver as it is faster and more efficient. I tried to record a macro but could not see any code related to opensolver. I need to access open solver using VBA just like we do for normal excel solver.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is how I got it working for a toy optimization problem I just created:

- Add the Opensolver reference to your VB project

[image: References menu...]

[image: OpenSolver reference]

- Call the solver as in this example code:

  ```
  Sub Test_OpenSolver()
      OpenSolver.RunOpenSolver , False
      'Q: Why False as a Second parameter?
      'A: MinimiseUserInteraction If True, all dialogs and messages will be suppressed. Use this when automating a lot of solves so that there are no interruptions. Defaults to False
  End Sub
  ```

Answer (score 1):

OpenSolver does not have any ability to record macros; it is not a feature our users have ever requested. However it does have a well documented VBA interface; see http://opensolver.org under Using OpenSolver.